# Creating RDF Lists using SPARQL

Tags: list, rdf, sparql

Is it possible to create RDF lists using SPARQL with the `INSERT` command or similar?

Comment: I have reworded the question to only ask the practical question and not to solicit opinion.  I believe the actual question is of interest to people and that it could be reopened as now worded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [blog posting](http://seaborne.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/updating-rdf-lists-with-sparql.html) covers the updating of RDF lists via SPARQL pretty comprehensively.

Comment: New link: https://afs.github.io/rdf-lists-sparql